# Parameter 'action' should have type assignable to 'Object' when trying to make Redux work with Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make redux work in my Typescript app right now, it actually seems to work but typescript seems to have some typing issues with it.

This is what comes up:

[image]

And this is my reducer code:

```
import { PopUpNotification } from "definitions/PopUpNotificationDefinitions";

interface IPopUpNotificationReducerState {
    popUpNotifications: Array<PopUpNotification>;
}

const initialState: IPopUpNotificationReducerState = {
    popUpNotifications: []
}

enum PopUpNotificationActions {
    ADD = "POPUPNOTIFICATION_ADD",
    DELETE = "POPUPNOTIFICATION_DELETE"
}

export interface AddPopUpNotification {
    type: PopUpNotificationActions,
    popUpNotification: PopUpNotification,
}

export interface DeletePopUpNotification {
    type: PopUpNotificationActions,
    popUpNotification: PopUpNotification,
}

export type PopUpNotificationAction = AddPopUpNotification | DeletePopUpNotification;

export function addPopUpNotification(popUpNotification: PopUpNotification): AddPopUpNotification {
    const addPopUpNotification: DeletePopUpNotification = {
        type: PopUpNotificationActions.ADD,
        popUpNotification: popUpNotification
    };

    return addPopUpNotification;
}

export function deletePopUpNotification(popUpNotification: PopUpNotification): DeletePopUpNotification {
    const deletePopUpNotification: DeletePopUpNotification = {
        type: PopUpNotificationActions.DELETE,
        popUpNotification: popUpNotification
    };

    return deletePopUpNotification;
}

export function popUpNotificationReducer(state = initialState, action: PopUpNotificationAction): IPopUpNotificationReducerState {

    switch (action.type) {
        case PopUpNotificationActions.ADD:
        return {
            popUpNotifications: [...state.popUpNotifications, action.popUpNotification]
        };
        case PopUpNotificationActions.DELETE:
        return {
            popUpNotifications: state.popUpNotifications.filter(notification => notification.Id !== action.popUpNotification.Id)
        }
    default:
        return initialState;
    }
}
```

I tried to follow the tutorial on the redux page as good as possible with small adaptions to my case here.

So, any hints as to where I am going wrong right now?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at working example of simple app that is shipped with Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. Example is based on TypeScript, Redux and React. So you'll have examples of actions, reducer etc.

To deploy example use Visual Studio 2017 Community -> New Project -> Visual C# -> .NET Core -> ASP.NET Core Web App -> In upper menu choose .NET Core 2.0 (this is important, as .NET Core 2.1+ templates are based on JavaScript) -> React.js and Redux -> and you'll have fully working typescript app with React and Redux